# Mobile app with api authorisation access

Tags: api, mobile, authorization

I'm creating a mobile app for customers that need to access an api that I use.
The api requires authentication and the app needs to call the api to receive some data that is specific to each individual customer(mobile app).

I just want to make sure that the right way to do this is for the mobile app to send the query to my server which will then make the authenticated api call and return the response to the mobile client?

or is it possible to have the mobile make the api calls directly, presumably using the same authorisation key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is primarily an opinion-based question, however I'll give it a go:

> **[paraphrased] Can my server act as an API proxy to make authenticated calls to another API on behalf of my *unauthenticated* users?**

This is a common occurrence in the API world, but some things you need to consider:

- It's an extra layer in between the user and the service, which adds time to the data transport. Make sure you build your proxy to be scalable or use a 3rd party service that can manage that on your behalf. Either way, don't forget to factor in cost.
- Usually service providers require authentication for a reason. Are you violating any license agreements by opening up their API like this?
- Is the authentication per-application, or per-user? If it's per-user (e.g. each user logs in and retrieves a unique `access_token`) then you're going to be making calls to the back-end API as a *user* instead of an *application*.
- Is the destination API rate-limited? Instagram's API, for example, only allows 5000 requests per hour. If you have 10,000 users that use it once per hour, you'll have already hit that limit.
- Are there security concerns opening up the destination API like this? Is there sensitive information that you need to protect? If so, opening it up like you do are you creating security holes?

> **Is it possible to have the mobile make API calls directly to the target API, presumably using the same authorization key?**

Absolutely this is possible - provided that you follow the authentication flow established by the target API. You'll want to consider the same list of concerns listed above though, in addition to:

- If you're using an auth flow like [OAuth2](http://oauth.net/2/), the standard dictates that each user should authenticate as themselves and make API calls using a unique `access_token`. Does your target API provider offer this service? If so, that's the way to go, that way if an access_token is compromised, only that user's data/account/etc. is at risk.
- If you're using app-level authentication (e.g. your app's `client_id` and `client_secret`) directly in your mobile app, be warned that it can be obtained and compromised with little effort, and thus an attacker could gain access to the entire target API this way.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer!, it's authenticated per application.

Comment: @raphael_turtle then so long as it's not rate-limited, and you don't have any security/license concerns, proxying is probably the way to go -- that way you keep the auth out of the mobile app. Keep in mind performance can be a concern though, if you've got lots of users, managing the proxy.

Comment: @raphael_turtle I also added another line to the first list about scalability and cost.